# Django easy_pdf easy_pdf is not defined

Tags: django, pdf-generation, pip

My problem might be simple to fix, but I don't really know how to deal with it. 
It cannot find easy_pdf, but it's already installed. Here's my `view` where I'd like to use it:

```
def ReportRequest(request):
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ReportForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        usrname = request.user
        q = Training.objects.filter(user=usrname, date__range=[form.cleaned_data['start'], form.cleaned_data['end']], type=form.cleaned_data['type'])
        quantity = q.count()
        if quantity == 0:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/notrainings/')
        start = form.cleaned_data['start']
        end = form.cleaned_data['end']
        type=form.cleaned_data['type']
        avg_distance = q.aggregate(Avg('distance'))
        avg_calories = q.aggregate(Avg('caloriesBurnt'))
        sum_length = q.aggregate(Sum('length'))
        sum_distance = q.aggregate(Sum('distance'))
        sum_calories = q.aggregate(Sum('caloriesBurnt'))
        athlete = request.user.profile
        filename = "raport.pdf"
        template = "report.html"
        context = {'form':form, 'start':start, 'end':end, 'athlete':athlete, 'q':q,
                   'type':type, 'avg_calories':avg_calories,'avg_distance':avg_distance,
                   'avg_calories':avg_calories, 'sum_distance':sum_distance, 'sum_calories':sum_calories}
        # return render_to_response('report.html', contekst, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        return easy_pdf.rendering.render_to_pdf_response(request, template=template, context=context, filename=filename, encoding=u'utf-8', **kwargs)
    else:
        return render_to_response('reportform.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    form = ReportForm()
    return render_to_response('reportform.html',{'form':form}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

It returns `NameError at /reportform global name 'easy_pdf' is not defined`, but I already have easy_pdf installed. Here are my `imports` connected with `easy_pdf`

```
from easy_pdf.views import PDFTemplateView
from easy_pdf import *
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Django problem, but a basic Python issue.

When you do `from easy_pdf import *`, the name `easy_pdf` is not defined: instead, all the elements under that name are imported into the current namespace. That is rarely a useful thing to do. Instead, do simply `import easy_pdf`.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, I'm completely new to Django and Python. Works like a charm.